# Cursor is not blinking after QlineEdit setInputMask()

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I am using setInputMask() to validate ipaddress in qlineEdit. But after using setInputMask(), cursor is not blinking.
Do anyone is having idea how this can be fixed to make cursor behave normal after setInputMask().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the focus using SetFocus() on the lineedit after setInputMask().

Comment: Hi,Yes I also tried to use SetFocus() but still it didnt work.Thanks